# clickhouse-client get error "Timeout exceeded while reading from socket"

Tags: clickhouse

I'm newbie to clickhouse, I'm trying to create a clickhouse database on my unbuntu 18.04 remote server, I follow instruction to install click house from DEB package in this link: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/getting_started/install/#from-sources

after that when I run command *clickhouse-client* it shows something like this :

```sh
root@busmap-api-test:~# clickhouse-client
ClickHouse client version 20.3.5.21 (official build)
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 209. DB::NetException: Timeout exceeded while reading from socket (127.0.0.1:9000)
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is the problem and how I can solve it?
Thanks,

Comment: let's check that CH-service is run: *service clickhouse-server status*

Comment: @vladimir yeah i got this : ``` clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data) Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-03-25 10:23:21 UTC; 3 days ago Main PID: 11193 (clickhouse-serv) Tasks: 59 (limit: 1152) CGroup: /system.slice/clickhouse-server.service └─11193 /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file=/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid ``` –

Comment: if you use a remote server, need to define the *--host* option (see for details https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/#command-line-options)

Comment: no , i mean that i'm create clickhouse database on my remote server through terminal on remote server , not create from my local machine

Comment: look at log-file: *cat /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log*. Check the config-file */etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml* and make sure that *<listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>* uncommented (restart service after change config).

Comment: i'm getting this after sudo nano cat /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log.
https://gyazo.com/ed61bd341f469239bfb4e98bd2ac7c79

Comment: seem likes i already using port 9000 so that i can not connect to localhost:9000 on clickhouse , how can i change the default port 9000 in config.xml of clickhouse to new one such as 9002 ?

Comment: see param [tcp_port](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server_settings/settings/#server_settings-tcp_port)

Comment: i have changed the tcp_port from 9000 to 9069 and restart clickhouse but when i run clickhouse-client it still connect to localhost:9000 and return with Code: 209. DB::NetException: Timeout exceeded while reading from socket (127.0.0.1:9000)

Comment: need to explicitly define this port - *clickhouse-client --port 9069* (see https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/#command-line-options)

Comment: yeah , i have tried but this time it return connection refused root@busmap-api-test:~# clickhouse-client --port=9096
ClickHouse client version 20.3.5.21 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9096 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9096)

Comment: i check which port are using on clickhouse and it present with port 9096 but still not why i got connection refuse when connect to it https://gyazo.com/96402cfcfd1f84fb9c621f4b24a5f6ef

Comment: maybe you misspelled: listened port 9069, but refused 9096 ?

Comment: omg you wasr right , i misspelled 9069 by 9096 , after change it i got new return ClickHouse client version 20.3.5.21 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9069 as user default.
Code: 516. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9069. DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name

Comment: haha finally it's work when i add --password , thank you a lot buddy

Comment: great, congratulations ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to resolve the issue:

- check that *clickhouse-server*-service started

```sh
service clickhouse-server status
```

- check the server logs to find the possible reason

```sh
cat /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log
```

- if occured the error 'Address already in use':

```sh
{} <Error> Application: Net Exception: Address already in use: [::1]:9000
{} <Error> Application: Net Exception: Address already in use: 127.0.0.1:9000
```

1. need to switch CH-server to any other port by editing [tcp_port](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server_settings/settings/#server_settings-tcp_port)-param in */etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml*-file:

```sh
..
<tcp_port>9032</tcp_port>
..
```

2. restart CH-server service:

```sh
service clickhouse-server restart
```

3. and connect this way

```sh
clickhouse-client --port 9032
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this problem too but I got it working with the default port.

The setting should be this way if you want to connect remotely and be able to use the loopback from localhost.

```
<listen_host>::1</listen_host>
<listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
```

This allows the loopback method to work (i.e `clickhouse-client no args`) on localhost to connect through the IPV6 route, and the remote connection (i.e `clickhouse-client -h <hostname>`) through the IPV4 connection.

My original problem was that i only used `<listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>` in my config which meant the`clickhouse-client no args` would not work on localhost. And I could not get both to work by adding `<listen_host>127.0.0.1</listen_host>`